# Send XML element as HTTP header using XForms

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I am quite new to XForms so please bear over with me. I would like to know if following can be done:

I have an HTML form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="search-string"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="search1" checked="checked" />Search option 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="search2" checked="checked" />Search option 2
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I would like to represent this in XForms and on submit convert it to an XML element like this:

```
<data>
    <search1>my search string</search1>
    <search2>my search string</search2>
</data>
```

The `search1` and `search2` elements should only be set if the corresponding checkboxes are set, and they are both populated with the string from the `search-string` input.

When the `data` element has been constructed I need to send it through a POST http request.

Can all this be done using solely XForms or do I need to employ JS or something?

PS: I am using XSLTForms if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with XForms without extra Javascript instructions. You need two instances: one to be submitted and another one to be used to fill the first one.

This should be something like this for the model part:

```
<xf:model>
  <xf:instance id="data">
    <data xmlns="">
      <search1/>
      <search2/>
    </data>
  </xf:instance>
  <xf:instance id="work">
    <work xmlns="">
      <b1 xsi:type="boolean"/>
      <b2 xsi:type="boolean"/>
      <search/>
    </work>
  </xf:instance>
  <xf:bind nodeset="instance('data')/search1" calculate="choose(instance('work')/b1,instance('work')/search,'')"/>
  <xf:bind nodeset="instance('data')/search2" calculate="choose(instance('work')/b2,instance('work')/search,'')"/>
  <xf:submission ref="instance('data') method="post" resource=".........."/>
</xf:model>
```

-Alain